# Why is React Bootstrap Card not showing in the browser? The page is empty despite the component being used

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to render a reusable Card in my "Rooms" page. However, it doesn't show up when I run npm start, and when I inspect, it shows 0 by 0 pixels. Below is the code:

I have CardC component here:

```
import React from "react";
//import "../css/community.css";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
//import coffee from "./Social_Rooms/images/coffee-shop.png";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";


const cardC = (props) => {
 return (
  <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
    {<Card.Img variant="top" src={props.item.imageSource} />}
    <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{props.item.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Subtitle>{props.item.subtitle}</Card.Subtitle>
    {<Card.Subtitle>{props.item.subtitle}</Card.Subtitle>}
    <Card.Text>{props.item.description}</Card.Text>
    <Button variant="outline-primary">Join</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
  );
};
export default cardC;
```

And I want to use it in this file:

```
   import React from "react";
   import Card from "react-bootstrap";
   import cardC from "../components/card";
   import coffee from "./images/coffee-shop.jpg";
   import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";


   const people = [
         {
           imageSource: { coffee },
           title: "How to Make First Impressions",
           subtitle: "2:30 - 4",
           subtitle: "5 people",
           description: "How to make a good iahfdfhalgalhfkghlahdklghklghaklgha",
          },
              ];

          const Rooms = (props) => {
          return (
           <div>
             <cardC item={people[0]} />
          </div>
                 );
              };

         export default Rooms;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and I see a small problem in the console, the name of your component: "cardC" -> "CardC" (camelCase -> PascalCase) and you have 2 subtitle (remove one):

```js
import React from "react";
// import Card from "react-bootstrap";
import CardC from "./components/card";
import coffee from "./images/coffee-shop.jpg";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";


const people = [
  {
    imageSource: { coffee },
    title: "How to Make First Impressions",
    subtitle: "2:30 - 4",
    // subtitle: "5 people",
    description: "How to make a good iahfdfhalgalhfkghlahdklghklghaklgha",
  },
];

const Rooms = (props) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <CardC item={people[0]} />
      </div>
  );
};

export default Rooms;
```

and

```js
import React from "react";
//import "../css/community.css";
// import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
// import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
// import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
//import coffee from "./Social_Rooms/images/coffee-shop.png";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";


const CardC = (props) => {
    return (
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            {<Card.Img variant="top" src={props.item.imageSource} />}
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{props.item.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Subtitle>{props.item.subtitle}</Card.Subtitle>
                {<Card.Subtitle>{props.item.subtitle}</Card.Subtitle>}
                <Card.Text>{props.item.description}</Card.Text>
                <Button variant="outline-primary">Join</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );
};
export default CardC;
```